# Can't stop reading lines in c++

Tags: c++

The following code is for a homework assignment due on 17 October. The problem states to "write a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of numbers. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and smallest numbers entered."

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

bool isNumeric(string aString)
{
    double n; 
    istringstream is; 
    cin >> aString;
    is.str(aString);
    is >> n;
    if (is.fail()) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}

vector<double> limits(vector<double> a)
{
    // Returns [min, max] of an array of numbers; has
    // to be done using std::vectors since functions 
    // cannot return arrays. 
    vector<double> res; 
    double mn = a[0]; 
    double mx = a[0]; 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (mn > a[i])
        {
            mn = a[i]; 
        }
        if (mx < a[i])
        {
            mx = a[i]; 
        }
    }
    res.push_back(mn); 
    res.push_back(mx); 
    return res; 
}

int main()
{
    string line = " "; 
    vector<string> lines; 
    vector<double> arr; 
    cout << "Enter your numbers: " << endl; 
    while (!line.empty() && isNumeric(line))
    {
        getline(cin >> ws, line); 
        if (line.empty() || !isNumeric(line))
        {
            break;
        }
        lines.push_back(line);
        transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), [](char32_t ch) {
            return (ch == ' ' ? '\000' : ch); 
        }); // Remove all spaces 
        arr.push_back(atof(line.c_str())); 
    }
    vector<double> l = limits(arr); 
    cout << "\nMinimum: " << l[0] << "\nMaximum: " << l[1] << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

The above code is what I have. However, it's not always outputting the correct maximum value and only outputs "0" for the minimum value. I can't seem to find what's wrong with this so if anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: You're trying to do two new things at once. Tackle them *separately*, and tell us which one you need help with.

Comment: Only one problem now. Happy now?!

Comment: If your input routine is working and you're just having trouble computing min/max, write a simpler test program with hard-coded input, and put that in your question.  If your problem is your input routine doesn't work, describe what it is doing and what's wrong.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why ++i and not I++? Should it not check in the zeroth spot?

Comment: @JeremyKahan: That's irrelevant.

Comment: @JeremyKahan A for loop with ++i instead of i++ is not missing the first number.

Comment: Definite progress! Now, by inspection, I see that you give `mn` the initial value `0`, and don't change it unless one of the given numbers is *less than that*. If I have a little time later, I'll try to find the problem with the max, but I suspect you aren't parsing the input properly.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @deviantfan

Answer (score 0):

For the minimum, your problem appears to be with the fact that in your `limits()` function, you initialize the value of min to 0. So if you have an array of [1, 2, 3, 4], it will check each element and, seeing that none of them is less than 0, leave 0 as the minimum. To fix this, you can set the initial value of `mn` to the first element of the array. Note that you will have to check to make sure the array has at least one element to avoid a possible overflow error.

For the maximum, I'm not sure what kind of inconsistencies you're having, but if your array only contained negative values, you would have the same problem as with minimum, where the initial value is higher than any of the actual values.

Comment: OK. Did the first part.

Comment: @ElEctric, are you still getting bad values for maximum? If so, could you provide examples?